# What is the origin of the akhlut's name?

Tags: mythical-creatures, origins, names, inuit

The *akhlut* is a creature from Inuit myth, a monstrous wolf that can take the shape of an orca. However, I haven't been able to find this word in any reliable Inuktitut dictionaries (looking for *akhlut*, *akłut*, or *ak&ut*—since *ł* is hard to type on American keyboards, it's often written *hl*, *lh*, or *&*).

Where does this creature's name come from?

Answer (score 4):

Found two Yupik dictionaries but neither had 'akhlut'. Then found the article below:

> http://offbeat.wikia.com/wiki/Akhlut
>
> **Akhlut**
>
> **Other Names** Kăk-whăn'-û-ghăt Kǐg-û-lu'-nǐk
>
> **Origin** Yupik
>
> **Location** Ice floes around the Bering Sea
>
> **Disposition** Malevolent
>
> Akhlut are shapeshifting spirits from Yupik myth. They appear as
>   either orcas or as wolves, and live among ice floes around the Bering
>   Strait. They are often depicted as a hybrid between an orca and a
>   wolf.
>
> **Appearance**   In the original folklore, akhlut were gigantic orcas who could shapeshift into equally massive wolves to hunt on land.[1]
>   In traditional art they are usually depicted in mid transformation,
>   with the features of both wolves and whales.[2] Most modern
>   interpretations portray them as creatures that are perpetually half
>   wolf, half orca rather than shapeshifters. They are generally
>   amphibious. An occasional variant of the creature appears as a beluga
>   whale, and can transform into a reindeer to traverse on land. It is
>   unclear whether this variation is carnivorous or not.[2]
>
> **Behavior**   Akhlut are known for their ferocity, and they hunt humans and animals alike. When hungry, they become wolves and run
>   across the land searching for prey. Once they have eaten their fill,
>   they return to the water and assume their orca forms once more.[3]
>   Wolf tracks leading to or from the ocean are an indicator that the
>   animal may be nearby.[1][2]
>
> **Anthropological information**   Nelson (The Eskimo About Bering Strait) claims that the creature is called Kăk-whăn'-û-ghăt
>   Kǐg-û-lu'-nǐk, and in orca form it is known as akh'-lut, and in wolf
>   form as kǐg-û-lu’-nǐk.[2] These may be mistranslations or alternate
>   dialects, as the central Yupik romanizations for "orca" and "wolf" are
>   "arrlug" and "kegg'luner" respectively[4]. It's unclear what the word
>   "Kăk-whăn'-û-ghăt" might mean. At any rate, it appears the name these
>   creatures are most well known by is simply a corruption of the Yupik
>   word for "orca".

Comment: Ahh, it's Yupik! That explains a lot. I don't have a dictionary on hand, but in modern Central Yupik, the sounds that used to be written "kh" are now written "gg" and "rr".

Comment: Don't know if it is helpful, but also came across:  https://www.uaf.edu/anlc/resources/yupik-inuit/  Comparative Yupik and Inuit
by Lawrence Kaplan